# update android studio version to 1.5.1

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I am a beginner in Android Studio, I used `help>>check for updates` to update my Android Studio, but then the code bugs,, the error appears:

> Error:(18, 54) error: cannot find symbol variable toolbar ,,,, Error:(21, 76) error: cannot find symbol variable fab,,,,,,,,,,Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

[image: see this image]

Comment: I had this issue too but I'm not sure how I fixed it... Do you use AppCompat?

Comment: It is not possible to get such bugs after updating except you deleted some SDK package or get some library replaced.

Comment: Please post the Gradle build setting. Something like this: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:15.+'
}